# Values that are stored in a C structure 'magically' change on their own

Tags: c, structure

I have a structure (with nesting) of the following type:

```
typedef struct {
   float precursor_mz;
   float precursor_int;
   int scan;
   float time;
   spectrum* spectra; /* Nested struct */
   int array_length;
   int mz_length;
   int int_length;
   char* mz_binary;
   char* int_binary;
   int hits;
} compound;
typedef struct {
   float mz_value;
   float int_value;
   int peaks;
} spectrum;
```

I transform this structure to allow me to use qsort, after which i store it back as my own 'type'. A few lines later in the code i wish to loop over the structure but somehow the values changed without me accessing them (in between). Code snippet below:

```
    // The transformating & qsort chunk
    for (i = 0; i < compounds->hits; i++) {
       spectrum test[(compounds+i)->spectra->peaks];
       for (j = 0; j < (compounds+i)->spectra->peaks; j++) {
           test[j] = *((compounds+i)->spectra+j);
       }
       qsort(test,(compounds+i)->spectra->peaks,sizeof(spectrum),compare_mz);
       for (j = 0; j < (compounds+i)->spectra->peaks; j++) {
           ((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->mz_value = test[j].mz_value;
           ((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->int_value = test[j].int_value;
           if ( j < 10) {
               printf("%i %i\t", i, j);
               printf("%f %f\n",((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->mz_value, ((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->int_value); // Here values are still correct 
           } 
       }
   }


/* Summing values that are in 'mass-tolerance' of each other */
   float int_total;
   float mz_int_total;
   for (i = 0; i < compounds->hits; i++) {
       counter = 0;
       printf("---\n");
       for (j = 0; j < (compounds+i)->spectra->peaks; j++) {
           lower_mass = ((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->mz_value - 0.05; //args->mass_tolerance;
           upper_mass = ((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->mz_value + 0.05; //args->mass_tolerance;
           if (j < 10) { 
               printf("%i %i\t", i , j);
               printf("%f %f\n",((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->mz_value, ((compounds+i)->spectra+j)->int_value);  // Here values are borked
           } 
           // Rest of the code chopped off as it should be irrelevant
```

This code however produces the following output:

```
tarskin@5-PARA-11-0120:/data/programming/C/Compound_Spectra$ ./Run -f ../PeptMoiety/32757_p_01.mzML -c 1
0 0 168.858765 32489.994141
0 1 168.960327 72930.046875
0 2 169.039993 4924.188477
0 3 169.913681 85340.171875
0 4 169.932312 2406.798096
0 5 171.000320 345949.593750
0 6 171.007950 1034718.312500
0 7 171.034088 882886.562500
0 8 171.034378 58554.589844
0 9 171.056320 871035.500000
---
0 0 168.858765 32489.994141
0 1 168.960327 72930.046875
0 2 169.039993 4924.188477
0 3 169.913681 85340.171875
0 4 0.000000 0.000000
0 5 169.932312 2406.798096
0 6 171.007950 1034718.312500
0 7 0.000000 0.000000
0 8 0.000000 0.000000
0 9 0.000000 0.000000
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening ?

**-- EDIT 1 --**

Alk requested the code for compare_mz, which is as follows:

```
int
compare_mz (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const spectrum *fa = (const spectrum *) a;
  const spectrum *fb = (const spectrum *) b;

  return (fa->mz_value > fb->mz_value)
             -(fa->mz_value < fb->mz_value);
}
```

The test case that i showed was for a single compound (so i = 1).

Comment: Can you simplify the test-case?  There's too much stuff going on in it right now.

Comment: Hmm.. you have quite a bit of debugging to do there. I would cut down the dataset to just two items that are out-of-order and step through with the debugger, keeping a careful note of values and indexes.  With your intimate knowledge of the complete code, that compiles, and knowing what i,j are doing, you should be able to find the problem.

Comment: Could you also provide the code for `compare_mz`?

Comment: @alk: Done, as edit 1. I doubt the problem lies in the qsort however as the first print never contains 0 values (for the complete (so no if j < 10) set).

Comment: @MartinJames: I have added a simple print to see the status of the indices, just to see if my indices were as i am expecting. The program is somehow doing really weird things, ie it replaces the value (0,5) with the value from (0,4) and the actual value (0,5) is lost. I am about ready to go start tearing my hair out o.O

Answer (score 1):

I strongly assume the memory referenced by `spectrum* spectra; /* Nested struct */` had not been allocated properly or had been (partly) released.

Try running your app using `valgrind`.

Also (in case you are using `gcc`): Do you get any compiler warnings if using `gcc`'s `-Wall` and/or `-pedantic` options?

---

Try the following mod/ and see if the app/ behaves different (the stack won't be touched between the to `for (j=0;..;..)` loops this way):

```
float int_total;
float mz_int_total;
spectrum test[(compounds+i)->spectra->peaks];

for (i = 0; i < compounds->hits; i++) {
  ...

/* Summing values that are in 'mass-tolerance' of each other */    
for (i = 0; i < compounds->hits; i++) {
  ...
```

Comment: @Bas Jansen: What happens if you move the declartion

    `spectrum test[(compounds+i)->spectra->peaks];`

out of the `for(;;)` context?

Comment: vaglrind gives it the all clear (except a known problem with inflate, elsewhere in the code) and no warnings show up with -Wall. No clue what pedantic is however, i will look that up. The first reflex i had when i encountered this problem was to free (compounds+i)->spectra and allocate it freshly but that doesn't change anything and it shouldn't as before and after the elements have to be allocated as floats (unless i am making a conceptual mistake there).